# when importing matplotlib in Jupyter Notebook no subpackages found

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to import matplotlib.pyplot (ver 3.2.1) in Jupyter Notebook but keep getting an error.
It might be worth mentioning that I have ArcGIS on my laptop where there is Python 2.7 and Matplotlib of version 1, not 3. And steps listed below work fine in PyCharm.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot
```

I tried uninstalling the whole thing with running pip uninstall matplotlib from command line (using Windows) and install it then back, but it also doesn't seem to have any effect.

Just importing matplotlib works fine until I run some code that includes its functions. Then errors arise, i.e.

```
import matplotlib
```

This cell runs with no errors. Then I try to display some basic stuff:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
df = pd.DataFrame([x,y], columns=['a','b','c','d','f'])
df['b'].hist()
matplolib.pyplot.show()
```

and get multiple traceback outputs

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in _get_plot_backend(backend)
   1599         # Because matplotlib is an optional dependency and first-party backend,
   1600         # we need to attempt an import here to raise an ImportError if needed.
-> 1601         import pandas.plotting._matplotlib as module
   1602 
   1603         _backends["matplotlib"] = module

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.artist'
```

I also tried this:

```
%matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Which resulted in yet another error:

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in find_gui_and_backend(gui, gui_select)
    286         # overwritten that.
    287         # WARNING: this assumes matplotlib 1.1 or newer!!
--> 288         backend = matplotlib.rcParamsOrig['backend']
    289         # In this case, we need to find what the appropriate gui selection call
    290         # should be for IPython, so we can activate inputhook accordingly

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'rcParamsOrig'
```

Help me please to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you be more specific? What is your  matplotlib version?

Comment: Please provide full traceback.

Comment: @SudeepaNadeeshan thank you. I use `pip3 list` to get all packages and versions, matplotlib is 3.2.1.

Comment: @БогданОпир   ```ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-71225e3ad40e> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the module as follows. A broken installation could lead to this error.

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall matplotlib
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! I tried but unfortunately, it hasn't solved the problem. So  I created a new virtual environment, activated it in conda prompt (specifying new PATHs)        `>set PATH=C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\py36env\Scripts;C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\py36env;%PATH%` ; `activate p36env`   and added needed packages (matplotlib, IPython, jupyter). `ipython kernel install --user --name=p36env` It works now.